# PyQt4: Icons are not displayed in the GUI

Tags: user-interface, path, icons, pyqt4

I implement a gui and the icons are not displayed in the GUI. The development path is a git clone (repositories directory). If i change the path to a simple local path the icons in the GUI will be displayed.

Any ideas for the cause or a solution to this problem?

The GUI is designed in QtDesigner. The code for the GUI is generated from pyuic4

Here it is:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(803, 502)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("icons/Server.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 803, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.menuFilter = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFilter.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuFilter"))
        self.menuFile = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuFile"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.toolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
        self.toolBar_2 = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolBar_2"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar_2)
        self.actionFilter = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("icons/Filter.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionFilter.setIcon(icon1)
        self.actionFilter.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionFilter"))
        self.actionFilter_by_Server = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionFilter_by_Server.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionFilter_by_Server"))
        self.actionExit = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionExit"))
        self.menuFilter.addAction(self.actionFilter_by_Server)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFilter.menuAction())
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionFilter)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Development Monitoring", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.menuFilter.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Filter", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.menuFile.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "File", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "toolBar", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.toolBar_2.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "toolBar_2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.actionFilter.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Filter", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.actionFilter.setStatusTip(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Filter", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.actionFilter.setShortcut(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+F", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.actionFilter_by_Server.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Filter by Server", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.actionExit.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Exit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

The code to show the GUI is here

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, app, parent= None):
        log.trace()
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.app=app
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: This seems like a filesystem issue. are you running the app from within the directory to where icons/ is relative? What does your dev path look like and where do you launch the app? Also dont forget that you actually need to __init__ a QMainWindow and not a QWidget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is most likely relative vs absolute paths to the icons on your filesystem, and where you are launching your app.
As a completely alternative suggestion to fix your issue, I recommend using a Resource file. you can create one from within Qt Designer, reference them in your GUI, and then you can convert it using pyrcc4 (similar to pyuic4). The icons will all be encoded into the file so you will no longer have filesystem path issues.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/designer-resources.html

An example of referencing a resource would end up looking like this:
`QtGui.QPixmap(":icons/Filter.png")`

Notice the ":" . This is a really good way to cache your icons and make them portable.